# Best way to represent size classes features in neural network

Tags: neural-networks, python, feature-engineering, keras

I have features representing a some specific size category, where a data sample has assigned one out of 110 possible size classes. What it is important that these classes are sorted from smallest to the largest, meaning class 0 is the smallest, while class 109 is the biggest.

```
Example:
| Sample   | Size B1        | Size B2 | Target - mass |
| -------- | -------------- |---------|---------------|
| 1        | 89             | 56      | 34000         |
| 2        | 34             | 41      | 30000         |
```

Currently I've used Keras Neural Network to train my model using the one-hot encoding on the size features.

I am wondering if there is a better way to represent such data, maybe as a continuous data as in my understanding one-hot categorical data would have no information that the size classes are ascending in sizes, whereas with the continuous data it might connect it better that by increasing the value the target also increases.